# Prove that $\frac{2^{4n + 2} + 1}{5}$ is composed for all $n \ge 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The problem is to prove that $$\frac{2^{4n + 2} +1 }{5}$$ is composed for every $n \ge 2$.

I've tried this way: write $2^{4n + 2} + 1$ as $1 - (-4)^{2n + 1}$ and $5 = 1 - (-4)$, then $$\frac{2^{4n + 2} + 1}{5} = \frac{1 - (-4)^{2n + 1}}{1 - (-4)} = 1 - 4 + 16 - 64 + \cdots + (-4)^{2n}$$

How to proceed from this?

Thanks!

Comment: Something seems to be wrong as $\;5\nmid (2^{4n+2}+2)\;$ ... Check your expression.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Just fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you can understand/prove the following

$$\frac{2^{4n+2}+1}5=\frac{3\cdot\left(2^{4n+1}-2^{4n}+\ldots-2^2+2\right)}5$$

But $\;5\nmid 6\;$ , so $\;5\;$ **must** divide the other factor as the whole thing is an integer since

$$4\cdot16^n+1=0\pmod 5$$

and thus the expression equals $\;6k\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb N\;$ ...composite.

Comment: $2^{4n+2}+1 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$.

Comment: How did you get an odd integer to be a multiple of six?

Comment: Rats. That's part of what was supposed to be an answer to the original post, @JyrkiLahtonen. Editing now. Thanx

Comment: @DanielFischer, edited now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

One approach. First observe that we must have
$$2^{4n + 2} = - 1 \pmod 5$$
This is true because it is equivalent to 
$$4 * 16^n = -1 \pmod 5$$
And there are various ways of showing this holds for all $n$.

So we know the expression is an integer. As for compositeness, a hint is as follows. Note that 
$$4x^4 + 1 = (2x^2 + 2x + 1)(2x^2 - 2x + 1)$$
What does this say about the numerator?